# convert a json file

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have a json file like below :

```
[   
    {"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"},
    {"foo": 50, "bar": "big data"}
]
```

I'd like to use jq to convert its content to the following :

```
[   
    {"name": 42, "value": "less interesting data"},
    {"name": 50, "value": "big data"}
]
```

I tried the command:

```
jq ' .[] | {name:.foo, value:.bar}',
```

but there's no comma between {...} sections :

```
{   
  "name": 42, 
  "value": "less interesting data"
}   
{   
  "name": 50, 
  "value": "big data"
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#mapx) instead.

```
map({ name: .foo, value: .bar })
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
jq '[.[] | {name:.foo, value:.bar}]'
```

Comment: Thanks!:) I was using a workaround:
`jq '.[] | {name:.foo, value:.bar}' | jq -s "."`